# Hibernate - Setar objeto chave estrangera sem buscar objeto. Direto pelo Id

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Alguém sabe se é possível eu setar um objeto que é chave estrangeira se ter que buscar ele. Ou seja, só setando o id direto?

**Exemplo:**

baixa.setIdEmpresa(daoEmpresa.buscaPorId(new Long(rsBaixa.getString(6))));

**forma que gostaria de fazer**

baixa.setIdEmpresa(new Long(rsBaixa.getString(6));

Answer (score 0):

Se você sabe que a entidade já existe no banco de dados, você pode utilizar o método `getReference` do `EntityManager`. Usando esse método, o Hibernate não vai buscar a entidade no banco de dados, ele vai apenas criar um *proxy*.

Seria basicamente assim:

```
//Ele não faz um SELECT aqui, apenas cria um proxy do objeto
Empresa empresa = entityManager.getReference(Empresa.class, idDaEmpresa);
baixa.setEmpresa(empresa);
```

O Hibernate só vai tentar carregar os atributos da classe caso você evoque algum método dela. Caso você tente evocar um método ou na hora do *flush* a entidade não existir no banco de dados, é lançada uma `EntityNotFoundException`.

Comment: Valeu Felipe. Havia me esquecido do PreparedStatement . Consegui resolver com ele. Muito menos transação para inserçoes.